# Android Facebook SDK 3 - request new permission but can't reauthorized

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have some problem with my code, i've followed hellofacebook example to post photo. But when i try to make new permission "publish_action", the code doesn't callback anything. Here is my code

```
private void performPublish(PendingAction action, boolean allowNoSession){
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session != null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"enter session unnull",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pendingAction = action;
        if(hasPublishPermission()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"enter haspublish",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            handlePendingAction();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Posted Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else if(session.isOpened()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"enter session opened",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermission = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(Third.this,PERMISSION);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermission);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Posted Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if(allowNoSession) {
            pendingAction = action;
            handlePendingAction();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me if you can, because i'm newbie with facebook SDK. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

according to new facebook sdk, you need to submit your app for review if you are publishing anything. after facebook approval you can upload picture by using any login. you can check this link for review process

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

https://github.com/sauce/guide/wiki/Facebook's-approval-process

Comment: is there any way to do it without submit my app?